# How to make blogger call the label of the current page and use it as a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blogger

Hi guys i recently stumbeled upon this website and i was wondering how he did pull it off 
this the link of the page

http://otakuurl.blogspot.com/search/?label=https://google.com&search=GO!

and as you noticed the link of the button changes accordingly to whats after the = mark
search the web but still didnt find any clues
if you know how to acheive the same result as the above website help me i want to build a website like that one with blogger platform

please do excuse my poor english thanks in advance

Comment: Why not simply debug what is happening with a combination of viewing the source and the F12 Developer Tools?

Comment: im trying to make similar website but i dont know how

Comment: @Mac I want to create a website like the one included in the question

Comment: What have you tried thus far? Post your code.

Comment: @fubar still didnt try any